# Draw 2 textures on a single quad directx

Tags: c++, directx, textures, directx-9

He,

I have a quad and I want to draw the same texture twice on it. When the texture is set I do a pixelshader that will distort the image. I have a Flexible Vertex Format with D3DFVF_TEX2. When I make my quad I give it 2 texture coördinates.

But what now? How can I draw the texture twice on the same quad with the same coordinates?

```
#define CustomFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_TEX2)
```

This is my quad.

```
CustomVertex vertices[4] = {
    { -width - 0.5f, height + 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }, //top left
    { width - 0.5f, height + 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f }, // top right
    { -width - 0.5f, -height + 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, //bottom left
    { width - 0.5f, -height + 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } // bottom right
};
```

Comment: why draw same texture twice?

Comment: I am implementing the oculus rift to a hobby project. I want to draw the same render twice. And then the pixelshader makes sure the right distorted views are made. For the left and right view ofcourse.

Comment: But distorting a 2D image won't give you a stereo view. Are you sure this is what you want to do?